# Radio button under ListiewBuilder not selecting item properly

Tags: json, flutter, dart, radio-button

I tring to create radio button list with my JSON data, but for now its not selecting item properly.
My API working like- User chooses any date, after choosing the date its call my API and showing data in ListView. Under ListView I'm trying to select those item with Radio Button.But for now Its selecting only 1 item.

[Full class file](https://gist.github.com/Roy-Tuhin/1f671c1e2744842164d60269a481e872)

`Widget build(BuildContext context) {`

`int _radioValue=1 ;`

```
  Container(
                  child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: DocVisitDays(),
                    builder:
                        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState !=
                          ConnectionState.done) {
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text("Somthing went wrong");
                      }

                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                              return Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  // color: Color(0xFF3E64FF),
                                  color: Colors.lightBlue[50],
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      //color: Color(0xFF3E64FF).withOpacity(0.3),
                                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.9),
                                      offset: const Offset(
                                        0.0,
                                        5.0,
                                      ),
                                      blurRadius: 3.0,
                                      spreadRadius: 0.5,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Radio(
                                      value: index,
                                      groupValue: _radioValue,
                                      onChanged: (value) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          _radioValue = value as int;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Visit Day: ${snapshot.data[index].visitDayName},\n Fee: ${snapshot.data[index].fee},  \n Discounted Fee: ${snapshot.data[index].discountedFee},  \n Booking Fee: ${snapshot.data[index].bookingFee} ",
                                      style:
                                          TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            });
                      }
                      return Text("Error while calling");
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: first, put `_radioValue` above the build method.

Comment: Okay. Working now!!

Comment: one more little help, can I get the selected Radio button value?

Comment: yeah, let me see again and you can upvote the comment XD

Comment: Never mind I think I got it by `Text('Selected Item = '+'$_radioValue')`

Comment: I am at the office too. So, can't focus on both things at once XD

Comment: new contributor, can't really Upvote now :(